# WirelessOnlinePath not found, batteryVoltagePath not found and batteryTemperaturePath not found error in android

Tags: java, android

When I run my android application logcat shows this kind of error.

```
10-22 04:37:02.863: E/BatteryService(290): usbOnlinePath not found
10-22 04:37:02.863: E/BatteryService(290): wirelessOnlinePath not found
10-22 04:37:02.873: E/BatteryService(290): batteryVoltagePath not found
10-22 04:37:02.873: E/BatteryService(290): batteryTemperaturePath not found
10-22 04:37:03.043: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(290): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
10-22 04:37:03.363: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
10-22 04:37:09.154: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
10-22 04:37:09.154: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
10-22 04:37:09.553: E/EventHub(290): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
10-22 04:37:09.553: E/EventHub(290): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
10-22 04:37:09.713: E/Trace(290): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-22 04:37:10.793: E/CommandListener(34): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
10-22 04:37:10.824: E/WifiStateMachine(290): Failed to disable IPv6: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '1 interface ipv6 wlan0 disable' failed with '400 1 Failed to change IPv6 state (No such file or directory)'
10-22 04:37:10.903: E/MobileDataStateTracker(290): default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
10-22 04:37:10.903: E/MobileDataStateTracker(290): default: Could not enable APN type "default"
10-22 04:37:13.633: E/Trace(349): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-22 04:37:15.443: E/ThrottleService(290): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-22 04:37:16.323: E/Trace(377): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-22 04:37:16.603: E/Trace(391): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-22 04:37:17.134: E/Trace(405): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-22 04:37:18.523: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
10-22 04:37:19.173: E/BluetoothAdapter(349): Bluetooth binder is null
10-22 04:37:19.173: E/BluetoothAdapter(349): Bluetooth binder is null
10-22 04:37:20.363: E/Trace(430): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-22 04:37:22.823: E/BluetoothAdapter(349): Bluetooth binder is null
10-22 04:37:22.903: E/ActivityThread(377): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
10-22 04:37:22.924: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(377): Could not find a dictionary pack
10-22 04:37:24.193: E/Trace(453): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-22 04:37:24.543: E/Trace(460): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-22 04:37:25.643: E/BluetoothAdapter(391): Bluetooth binder is null
10-22 04:37:28.753: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 04:37:28.753: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 04:37:28.753: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 04:37:28.763: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 04:37:28.763: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 04:37:28.763: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-22 04:37:28.773: E/BluetoothAdapter(290): Bluetooth binder is null
10-22 04:37:28.793: E/BluetoothAdapter(290): Bluetooth binder is null
10-22 04:37:28.803: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-22 04:37:28.803: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-22 04:37:28.803: E/SoundPool(290): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
```

But my app is running normally. Can anyone plz be so kind enough to explain why this kind of error is coming and how should I correct them?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your AVD might be corrupt. Try creating a new one and running your app on that.

Comment: I've created 5 more emulators but same result :(. My emulator is in 4.2 version.

Comment: Bummer.  I've only had those errors once, and a new AVD did it for me. I assume you've tried restarting the IDE?

Comment: Oh, sweet! I've been digging around for other solutions. Couldn't find anything else. Glad to help. What finally did it? New AVD? Restart? A li'l o' both?

Comment: Both. Thanx for your kind explanations :)